# How can I get RSS feed for a custom page?

Tags: rss

I have a custom page on my blog that doesn't display [RSS feed](http://www.slashgeek.net/geekshop/). You can see the [code here](http://pastebin.com/VtjD1SAH) for the custom page. I am not sure what I need to do to make rss feed for each individual post on that page. I am not much in php myself so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own feeds in wordpress.

Add this to functions.php:

```
function my_customfeed() {
load_template( TEMPLATEPATH . 'your-customfeed.php');
}
add_action('do_feed_customfeed', 'my_customfeed', 10, 1);
```

This will enable a new feed called customfeed.

Now you can create your-customfeed.php in your theme directory for the new rss.
To make things easier you can copy the rss2 wordpress template from /wp-includes/feed-rss2.php and adapt with the code of your custom page.

Then you can call your new feed with http://yoursite.com/?feed=customfeed.

customfeed can be any unique name you like, just make sure to replace in all these places, including the action name do_feed_customfeed.

**ANOTHER METHOD  (doesn't need to add code in functions.php)**

A easier way to do it is to create a template for the feed like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Feed
*/

$posts = query_posts(array('post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => get_wizy('portfolio_num_projects')));

include('wp-includes/feed-rss2.php');
?>
```

And then create a blank Page in wordpress (it could be named anything, like My custom feed) and in the sidebar choose the template you created (it has the same name has it is written in Template Name:..).

Now when you go to the url of the page you've just created, you have your feed.

Comment: what do you mean by "adapt with the code of your custom page" what exactly do I have to change?

Comment: I  will edit my answer with an example of how you could create your feed template

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Now I need to customize it to my liking. I also understood how the process work after your edit.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress can create via hook an new feed, but the content and the format of the feed is in your todos.

See the follow plugin, create a feed for drafts of post type `post` in WordPress and you find this feed on the URL `example.com/?feed=drafts` The key `drafts` comes from the init in this plugin `add_feed( 'drafts', array( $this, 'get_draft_feed') );`. The content and xml markup comes from method `get_draft_feed`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Drafts Feed
 * Plugin URI:  http://bueltge.de/wordpress-feed-fuer-entwuerfe/829/
 * Description: Add a new Feed for drafts: <code>/?feed=drafts</code>
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      Frank Bültge
 * Author URI:  http://bueltge.de/
 * Licence:     GPLv3
 * Last Change: 12/20/2012
 */

//avoid direct calls to this file, because now WP core and framework has been used
if ( ! function_exists( 'add_filter' ) ) {
    header('Status: 403 Forbidden');
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    exit();
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'Draft_Feed' ) ) {
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Draft_Feed', 'init' ) );

    class Draft_Feed {

        protected static $classobj = NULL;

        /**
        * Handler for the action 'init'. Instantiates this class.
        * 
        * @access  public
        * @return  $classobj
        */
        public static function init() {

            NULL === self::$classobj and self::$classobj = new self();

            return self::$classobj;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor, init in WP
         * 
         * @return  void
         */
        public function __construct() {

            add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'add_draft_feed') );
            if ( is_admin() ) {
                add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', array( $this, 'add_dashboard_widget') );
                add_action( 'admin_head', array( $this, 'add_my_css') );
                add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'textdomain') );
            }
        }

        /**
         * Load language file for translations
         * 
         * @return  void
         */
        public function textdomain() {

            load_plugin_textdomain( 'draft_feed', FALSE, dirname( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '/languages' );
        }

        /**
         * Return the drafts
         * 
         * @param   Integer $post_per_page for count of drafts
         * @return  Array 
         */
        public function get_drafts( $posts_per_page = 5 ) {

            $drafts_query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'draft',
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
                'orderby' => 'modified',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            ) );

            return $drafts_query->posts;
        }

        /**
         * Get dashbaord content
         * 
         * @param  Array $drafts
         * @return void
         */
        public function dashboard_recent_drafts( $drafts = FALSE ) {

            if ( $drafts )
                return;

            $drafts = $this->get_drafts();

            if ( $drafts && is_array( $drafts ) ) {

                $list = array();
                foreach ( $drafts as $draft ) {
                    $url    = get_edit_post_link( $draft->ID );
                    $title  = _draft_or_post_title( $draft->ID );
                    $user   = get_userdata($draft->post_author);
                    $author = $user->display_name;
                    $item   = '<a href="' . $url . '" title="'
                        . sprintf( __( 'Edit &#8220;%s&#8221;', 'draft_feed' ), esc_attr( $title ) ) . '">' 
                        . $title . '</a> ' . __( 'by', 'draft_feed' ) . ' ' 
                        . stripslashes( apply_filters( 'comment_author', $author ) ) 
                        . ' <abbr title="' . get_the_time( __( 'Y/m/d g:i:s A' ), $draft ) . '">' 
                        . get_the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ), $draft ) . '</abbr>';
                    $list[] = $item;
                }
            ?>
            <ul>
                <li><?php echo join( "</li>\n<li>", $list ); ?></li>
            </ul>
            <p class="textright"><a href="edit.php?post_status=draft" class="button"><?php _e( 'View all', 'draft_feed' ); ?></a></p>
            <?php
            } else {

                _e( 'There are no drafts at the moment', 'draft_feed' );
            }
        }

        /**
         * Add Dashbaord widget
         * 
         * @return  void
         */
        public function add_dashboard_widget() {

            wp_add_dashboard_widget(
                'dashboard_recent_drafts',
                __( 'Recents Drafts', 'draft_feed' ) . ' <small>' 
                    . __( 'of all authors', 'draft_feed' ) . '</small>',
                array( $this, 'dashboard_recent_drafts')
            );
        }

        /**
         * Add custom css, inline
         * 
         * @return  String $output
         */
        public function add_my_css() {

            $output  = '';
            $output .= "\n";
            $output .= '<style type="text/css">'."\n";
            $output .= '<!--'."\n";
            $output .= '#dashboard_recent_drafts abbr {' . "\n";
            $output .= 'font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, "Bitstream Vera Sans", sans-serif;' . "\n";;
            $output .= 'font-size: 11px;' . "\n";
            $output .= 'color: #999;' . "\n";
            $output .= 'margin-left: 3px;' . "\n";
            $output .= '}'."\n";
            $output .= '-->'."\n";
            $output .= '</style>'."\n";

            echo $output;
        }


        /**
         * Add feed with key 'drafts'
         * 
         * @return  void
         */
        public function add_draft_feed() {

            // set name for the feed
            // http://examble.com/?feed=drafts
            add_feed( 'drafts', array( $this, 'get_draft_feed') );
        }


        /**
         * Create RSS2 feed
         * 
         * @return void
         */
        public function get_draft_feed() {

            $items = $this->get_drafts( 20 );

            if ( ! headers_sent() )
                header( 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ), TRUE );
            $more = 1;

        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) . '"?' . '>'; ?>

<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    <?php do_action('rss2_ns'); ?>
>

<channel>
    <title><?php bloginfo_rss( 'name' ); wp_title_rss(); ?></title>
    <atom:link href="<?php self_link(); ?>" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link><?php bloginfo_rss( 'url' ) ?></link>
    <description><?php bloginfo_rss( 'description' ) ?></description>
    <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), false ); ?></pubDate>
    <generator>http://bueltge.de/</generator>
    <language><?php echo get_option( 'rss_language' ); ?></language>
    <sy:updatePeriod><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_period', 'hourly' ); ?></sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_frequency', '1' ); ?></sy:updateFrequency>
    <?php do_action('rss2_head'); ?>
    <?php
    if ( empty($items) ) {
        echo '<!-- No submissions found yet. //-->';
    } else {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
    ?>
        <item>
            <title><?php echo stripslashes( apply_filters( 'comment_author', $item->post_title ) ); ?></title>
            <link><?php echo stripslashes( apply_filters( 'comment_author_url', get_permalink($item->ID) ) ); ?></link>
            <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', $item->post_date ); ?></pubDate>
            <dc:creator><?php echo stripslashes( apply_filters('comment_author', $item->post_author) ); ?></dc:creator>

            <guid isPermaLink="false"><?php echo stripslashes( 
                apply_filters('comment_author_url', $item->guid)
            ); ?></guid>
            <?php if ( $item->post_excerpt != '' ) { ?>
            <description><![CDATA[<?php echo trim(
                stripslashes( apply_filters('comment_text', $item->post_excerpt) )
            ); ?>]]></description>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <description><![CDATA[<?php echo strip_tags(
                trim( stripslashes( apply_filters('comment_text', $item->post_content) ) )
            ); ?>]]></description>
            <?php } ?>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php echo trim(
                stripslashes( apply_filters( 'comment_text', $item->post_content ) )
            ); ?>]]></content:encoded>
            <?php do_action( 'rss2_item' ); ?>
        </item>
    <?php
        } 
    }
    ?>
    </channel>
</rss>
    <?php
        }

    } // end class
} // end if class exists
```