# Adding a second RSS feed

Tags: rss, feed

I have a Wordpress 4.Current blog with a RSS feed for the most recent 10 posts.

I would like to have a second RSS feed that has ALL my posts.

I have tried a few plugins, but none do what I want.

**Please don't ask me why, this is a simple enough technical question, I think it is stated clearly, and I'm just looking for a technical solution.**

Comment: Could you elaborate on your _reasons_ why do you need it? It might not be practical, depending on purpose and quantity of posts.

Comment: If you like the same rss feed, but only the count of post is the difference, then change the value on settings. But think, the most readers use only the last x post from a feed. If you like a custom feed, then it is possible to a new feed, new url for this via core functions. Like this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76712/how-can-i-get-rss-feed-for-a-custom-page)

Comment: @Rarst I want a second feed so user has the choice between subscribing to the most recent 10, or get a feed of all 40 posts

Comment: How would experience be any different if two feeds contain same posts? Feed readers will store same older items anyway, it would only matter if you post at such a high rate that 10 items feed needs to be checked exceptionally often to catch all updates.

Comment: @bueltge I think the second custom feed is what I need

Comment: @Rarst No, it also matters to new users. The normal feed they see is 10 long and can't get the earlier posts.

I'm looking for a technical solution to the technical problem outlined.